# Как в c# выбирать информацию между html тегами?

Tags: c#, теги, html

есть html тег

```
string html = "<p> text </p>";
```

или

```
string html = "<div> text </div>";
```

как получить text?

Comment: Постарайтесь более конкретизировать вопрос. Какую именно структуру может иметь html? Это один тег или может быть иерархия узлов? По каким критериям нужно нужно выбирать "text"?

Ответ на текущий вопрос такой:
`System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("<p>text</p>").Value`

Answer (score 1):

[Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net)

Comment: @huxi, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

И еще один пример вдогонку: [Хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112325/)

Comment: @No_Com, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.